# How do I multiply the value in the textbox and the column in listview?

Tags: vb.net

[See pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHYWX.jpg)I'm not familiar with vb.net. So, what I'm trying to do is when I click the chosen product and I put the qty. The Total price will show the multiplied value of the qty and price in the listview. I put the code in case 2 since it is the price but when I run it, it displays 0 then when I change it with a value of 2, it doesn't multiply. Here's my code so far:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form2
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("server=.\SQL;database=try;Trusted_Connection=TRUE")
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim cmd2 As SqlCommand
    Dim rdr As SqlDataReader

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        con.Open()
        con.Close()

        list()

    End Sub
    Sub list()
        con.Open()


        cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ProductTable", con)
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        If rdr.HasRows Then
            Do While rdr.Read()
                Dim arr As String() = New String(2) {}
                Dim itm As ListViewItem

                arr(0) = rdr("productID")
                arr(1) = rdr("product")
                arr(2) = rdr("price")

                itm = New ListViewItem(arr)
                ListView1.Items.Add(itm)


            Loop

        End If

        con.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
        With Me.ListView1
            Dim i As Integer
            For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
                i = item.Index
            Next

            Dim innercounter As Integer = 0
            For Each subItem As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem In ListView1.Items(i).SubItems
                Dim myString As String = ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(innercounter).Text
                Select Case innercounter
                    Case 2
                        txtqty.Text = 0.ToString()
                        txtqty.Text = CType(0, String)
                        txtqty.Text = CStr(0)
                        txtqty.Text = "0"
                        txtprice.Text = myString * txtqty.Text

                End Select
                innercounter += 1
            Next
        End With
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Set `Option Strict On` text controls contain text.  They are not numbers and cannot be multiplied unless and until you convert to numbers. Text controls also usually requires input from a user which cannot happen in form load. Same with choosing a ListView item. Those global DB provider objects will also cause your headaches. Read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: You must convert both `strings` into `integer`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `Function` to multiply values in `Textbox` and `ListView`

```
Private Function calculate() As Integer
    Dim price As Integer
    Dim qty As Integer
    Dim totalPrice As Integer
    Try
        price = CInt(ListView1.Items(ListView1.FocusedItem.Index).SubItems(2).Text)
        qty = CInt(txtqty.Text)
        totalPrice = price * qty
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Invalid Inputs!")
    End Try
    Return totalPrice
End Function
```

Convert the `Strings` into `Integers` so that you can multiply it. `CInt()` is the code for converting texts to int. Surround it by `Try Catch` to handle invalid inputs.

Then call the `Function` in your `ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged` or `txtqty_TextChanged`

```
Private Sub txtqty_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtqty.TextChanged
    txtprice.Text = calculate().ToString
End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    txtprice.Text = calculate().ToString
End Sub
```